# Python Lambda: Delete Snapshots but Exclude by Tag

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm fairly new to python and writing lambda functions on AWS. I read a lot of blogposts and articles now and eventually stumbled over the following script that I'm currently "testing".

```
        … 
        # Connect to region
        ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=reg)
        
        # grab all snapshot id's
        result = ec2.describe_snapshots( OwnerIds=[account_id] )
        # result = ec2.describe_snapshots( Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:retention', 'Values': ['keep']},{'Name': 'owner-id','Values': ['111111111111']}] )
    
        for snapshot in result['Snapshots']:
            print "Checking snapshot %s which was created on %s" % (snapshot['SnapshotId'],snapshot['StartTime'])

            # for tag in snapshots:

            …
```

What I'm after is that I delete all snapshots older then the retention days BUT with the exception of all snapshots that have a tag "retention" with value "keep".

Can anyone help me out here on how to do that inside the for loop?

The question is: Do I even do that in the for loop and filter somehow **snapshot[Tags]** or something or do I use a filter above?

I guess if I use the filter within describe_snapshots I only get the snapshots with the tag.
But I want to retrieve all snapshots and then run the delete command for all but the ones with the tag.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you tell me if your all snapshots have at-least one tag ?  OR few have with tags and few are without tags.

Comment: updated code , just try and let me know if you face any issue. You only have to change 
`retention_days = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)` the retention days as per your need.

Comment: have you tested it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I list all the snapshots ID which need to retain in `not_delete_snaps` list. and then calculated `retention_days`. You can change as per your need.
Finally, loop all the snapshots and checked if snashot id is exist in `not_delete_snaps`. If exist, then dont do anything, just `continue`. Then checked if snapshot ID is older than `retention_days`. if yes then deleting all the older snapshots.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

    snap_list = []
    marker = None
    paginator = ec2_client.get_paginator('describe_snapshots')
    while True:
        page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
            OwnerIds=['111111111111'],
            PaginationConfig={
                # 'MaxItems': 100,
                'PageSize': 100,
                'StartingToken': marker
            }
        )
        for page in page_iterator:
            snap_list += page['Snapshots']
        try:
            marker = page['Marker']
        except KeyError:
            break

    retention_days = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
    for item in snap_list:
        start_time = item['StartTime']
        start_time_new = start_time.replace(tzinfo=None)
        keys = list(item.keys())
        try:
            if 'Tags' in keys and item['Tags'][0]['Key'] == 'retention' and item['Tags'][0]['Value'] == 'keep':
                continue
            if retention_days > start_time_new:
                ec2_client.delete_snapshot(
                    SnapshotId=item['SnapshotId'])
        except ClientError as e:
            if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidSnapshot.InUse':
                print('Skipping snapshots which are in use')
            else:
                print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
```

Comment: Instead of making 2 calls to `describe_snapshots`, you may want to make one call without the filters and  skip deleting those whose `retention` tag has value `keep`. possibly add pagination as well.

Comment: good point. I can add pagination. will do. But, what if few snapshots does not have any tags? then checking on basis of tags will throw error. If all snapshots have tags then one call for `describe_snapshots` is enough.

Comment: You can always add the check to see if they key ‘retention’ is present or not. Or just filter on the key and not on the value.

Comment: its not about `retention`. I can add check if there is any tag on it. If a snapshot does not have any Tag, then when we describe it, Tags attributes does not show. It show other attributes like Description, OwnerId etc but not `Tags`.

Comment: Yup. Same thing. Add a check to see if Tags key is there or not. If not skip the whole check or may be let OP decide what he/she wants to do.

Comment: Updated code with pagination and checks with Tags key. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much @saranjeetsingh … I just wanted to test this right now but I get ```module initialization error: The config profile (default) could not be found``` … where do I find or set this profile?

Comment: I simply deleted the profile parameter from the Session, and it seems to be working. However … ```module initialization error: An error occurred (InvalidSnapshot.InUse) when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: The snapshot snap-0d56d3ba40166f9d2 is currently in use by ami-054b9729083e831d1``` as a result of  ```Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "module initialization error"
}
``` is it possible to skip snapshots IN USE? So it wouldn't throw an error?

Comment: @matt I forgot to mention about custom session.  you have to change it as per your set up. you can see here for more info. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/session.html

Comment: @matt I have updated code with exception handling. now it should delete without any error.

Comment: for more info about error handling in boto3 https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/client_upgrades.html#error-handling

Comment: @saranjeetsingh it "kind of" works :) thank you so much. With Test-Running it I was able to delete almost 5000 snapshots now. However when running I now have 1400 snapshots left but it seems like it still throws an error: https://i.imgur.com/U0c4UPa.png

Comment: @saranjeetsingh I ran a few times now without errors, now when clicking TEST it throws this error. ```Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function': 'module' object has no attribute 'lambda_handler'```